# Store canvas coordinates of drawing

Tags: javascript, android, css, html, canvas

I'm just screwing around a bit and so I made this Android unlock style thingy. It uses `<canvas>` to let someone draw and then colors in the dots accordingly. However, what I want to do now is store the coordinates of the drawing in a table. So, next time the drawing can be checked against the one stored.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xugav

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
    prevX = 0,
    currX = 0,
    prevY = 0,
    currY = 0,
    dot_flag = false;

var x = "#000",
    y = 1;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;

    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
        findxy('move', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
        findxy('down', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
        findxy('up', e)
    }, false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) {
        findxy('out', e)
    }, false);
}

function buttonCoords(id) { // replaces the coorX functions, takes element id as parameter
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();    
    var x = position.left+7;
    var y = position.top+7;
    xend = x + 19;
    yend = y + 19;

    return {
        top: y,
        bottom: yend,
        left: x,
       right: xend
    };    
}

function draw() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
    ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
    ctx.strokeStyle = x;
    ctx.lineWidth = y;
    ctx.stroke();
    var i = 0;
    var k = 0;

    var coords = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton1');
    var coords2 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton2');
    var coords3 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton3');
    var coords4 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton4');
    var coords5 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton5');
    var coords6 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton6');
    var coords7 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton7');
    var coords8 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton8');
    var coords9 = buttonCoords('patternlockbutton9');
    if (currX >= coords.left && currX <= coords.right && currY >= coords.top && currY <= coords.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton1").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords2.left && currX <= coords2.right && currY >= coords2.top && currY <= coords2.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton2").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords3.left && currX <= coords3.right && currY >= coords3.top && currY <= coords3.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton3").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords4.left && currX <= coords4.right && currY >= coords4.top && currY <= coords4.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton4").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords5.left && currX <= coords5.right && currY >= coords5.top && currY <= coords5.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton5").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords6.left && currX <= coords6.right && currY >= coords6.top && currY <= coords6.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton6").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords7.left && currX <= coords7.right && currY >= coords7.top && currY <= coords7.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton7").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords8.left && currX <= coords8.right && currY >= coords8.top && currY <= coords8.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton8").addClass("touched");
    } else if (currX >= coords9.left && currX <= coords9.right && currY >= coords9.top && currY <= coords9.bottom) {
        $("#patternlockbutton9").addClass("touched");
    }   

    ctx.closePath();
}

function erase() {
    var m = confirm("Want to clear");
    if (m) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
    }
}

function findxy(res, e) {
    if (res == 'down') {
        prevX = currX;
        prevY = currY;
        currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
        currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

        flag = true;
        dot_flag = true;
        if (dot_flag) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.fillStyle = x;
            ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
            ctx.closePath();
            dot_flag = false;
        }
    }
    if (res == 'up' || res == "out") {
        flag = false;
    }
    if (res == 'move') {
        if (flag) {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
            console.log(currX, currY);
            draw();
        }
    }
}

function print(){
    var c = document.getElementById("can");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(10,10,50,50);
    console.log(imgData);
    var img = c.toDataURL("image/png");
    var element = document.getElementById("container");
    element.innerHTML = "<img src='"+img+"'><p>"+imgData+"</p>";

}

</script>
<style>
    .patternlockbutton{
        border-color: red;
        background-color: transparent;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        display:block;
        width:33px;
        height:33px;
        float:left;
        margin:26px;
        -ms-touch-action: none;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
        border-top-left-radius: 50px;
        border-top-right-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    }
    .touched{
        border-color: red;
        background-color: red;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        display:block;
        width:33px;
        height:33px;
        float:left;
        margin:26px;
        -ms-touch-action: none;
        border-style: solid;
        border-width: 5px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-topleft: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
        border-top-left-radius: 50px;
        border-top-right-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px;
        -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    }
    #can {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 99;
        display: block;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div style="width:300px;height:400px; position: relative;">
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton1"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton2"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton3"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton4"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton5"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton6"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton7"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton8"></div>
        <div class="patternlockbutton" id="patternlockbutton9"></div>
        <canvas id="can" width="300px" height="400px"></canvas>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="clear" id="clr" size="23" onclick="erase()" style="position:absolute;top:55%;left:15%;">
    <button onclick="print()">Console.log</button>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get data that is currently on a HTML5 Canvas we simply need to use `ctx.getImageData(...)`. This gets information of every pixel within a certain rectangle that you define, we are interested in the pixels themselves. That's stored in `imageData.data` like so:

```
imageData.data[0] -> pixel1 red value
imageData.data[1] -> pixel1 green value
imageData.data[2] -> pixel1 blue value
imageData.data[3] -> pixel1 alpha value
imageData.data[4] -> pixel2 red value
...
```

So pixels are stored in sets of 4. If you want the entire Canvas then we do:

```
ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

To check for differences between two images we get the image data of both, then we loop through the pixel values and check for differences. Here is an example of getting two different images. In this example I'm using a third image to draw in red the difference:

```
var X = 0, Y = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < img1Data.data.length; i += 4) {  
    if(img1Data.data[i] != img2Data.data[i] || 
    img1Data.data[i+1] != img2Data.data[i+1] || 
    img1Data.data[i+2] != img2Data.data[i+2] || 
    img1Data.data[i+3] != img2Data.data[i+3]) {
        ctx_diff.fillRect( X, Y, 1, 1 );
    }
    X += 1;
    if(X >= canvas1.width) { Y+=1; X = 0 }
}
```

The whole code is in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/toccbL2h/)

Here is the output:

[image: Output of image difference code]

Comment: It appears there is a problem with the JSFiddle website, looks like some fiddles that were made without using an account were removed. I remade the fiddle via account for safety here: http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/toccbL2h/

Comment: Okay, thanks! I added this to my code, but somehow it isn't recognising some of the parts. I pasted it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/izKCc

Comment: It seems to recognize both the block and the lines drawn when I click `Console.log()`. Do you mean that the red circles are not showing? If so that's simply because they are not apart of the canvas.